# Calculate Win/Loss Streak Query

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I'm trying to find a way to calculate win/loss streak for a user. My table has a field defined as "W/L" and each win is entered as "W" and each loss is entered as "L" Here is what the current table looks like:

```
ID   Result

1    L

2    W

3    W

4    W
```

Here is an example I found, seems pretty straight forward but I'm apparently missing an operator though. Not sure what I'm missing.

```
SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN Result = 'W' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as Wins, 
       SUM(CASE WHEN Result = 'L' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as Losses 
FROM Table1
```

Is it best to create a query for this or more suited for a VBA type function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use something like,

```
SELECT 
    Sum(IIF(Result = 'W', 1, 0)) As TotalWins, 
    Sum(IIF(Result = 'L', 1, 0)) As TotalLooses
FROM Table1;
```

Comment: Sorry about that comment, someone mentioned that this is not a valid solution, but then chose to delete it. So I deleted my comment too. I am glad you got it working, please feel free to mark this as answer, if this has helped you. Good luck.